# Does $X_t$ independent of $(Y_t: t)$ for all $t$ imply that $(X_t : t), (Y_t: t)$ are independent.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X=(X_t)$ and $Y=(Y_t)$ be sequences of categorical random variables. Suppose that for each $t$, $X_t$ is independent of the sequence $Y$. Does this imply that the sequence $X$ is independent of the sequence $Y$? Intuitively I would say yes, because I do not see how $X$ and $Y$ can dependent on each other. Can someone tell me more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple counterexample, take $X_2,X_3,\ldots$ and $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ i.i.d. Bernoulli$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $X_1=X_2+Y_1+Y_2 \mod 2$. Then you have $X_i$ independent of $Y$, but you don't even have $(X_1,X_2)$ independent of $(Y_1,Y_2)$, let alone $X$ independent of $Y$.

EDIT: even simpler, you may take $Y_1,Y_2,X_1$ i.i.d. coin flips, $X_2=X_1+Y_1+Y_2 \mod 2$ and $X_3=Y_3=X_4=Y_4=\ldots=0$

Answer (score 1):

Take two dependent random variables $A,B: [0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ and define $$X_t := A(t), Y_t := B(t)$$ then each $X_t$ and $Y_t$ is constant hence each $X_t$ is independent of $Y$ but it holds $X = A, Y=B$ and by assumption $X$ and $Y$ are dependend.